# Replace content in a gzip file without decompressing it

Tags: java, compression

I'm receiving from a webservice xml files compressed in gzip format. The original size of the xmls is about 80Mb, and the compressed version is about 10Mb. These xml files are stored in our cache.

The xml root contains an attribute representing an 8-digit unique ID. So, when we serve a response from cache, we need to change this ID with another one received from another webservice before returning the xml to the end user.

The process should be:

1. Decompress the cache xml.
2. Replace the cached ID by one received from a webservice.
3. Compress the file again and return it to the client.

Is it possible to perform this replacement without decompressing the whole document and compressing it again? Any kind of partial read and write?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are decompressing, replacing, and then compressing again? There may be room for improvement

Comment: Not coded yet, but the idea is: 1. create a byte[] with the uncompressed document (using gzipinputstream). 2. Replace the 8-digit byte by byte (avoiding any temporary copy). 3. compress this byte[] using gzipoutputstream.

Answer (score 0):

No. You'd have to decompress it, at least to find where and how the ID is coded. Then you can either a) be really smart and figure out how to reassemble a stream with a different ID but the same number of bits, using the currently defined code tables, essentially solving a puzzle (assuming that it can be solved at all), or b) recompress the whole thing with the new ID.

If you are in control of the compression of your starting point, you could specially prepare the stream for this by switching to no compression right before the ID, flushing the block, a stored block, right after the ID, and then continuing with compression. You could note where in the output stream that is. Then you could later replace the ID, which appears in the stream as those bytes directly. You would also need to update the CRC, for which you can exclusive-or the original CRC with a "raw" CRC of the exclusive-or of the old uncompressed data and the new uncompressed data. That is just the exclusive-or of the old ID and the ID, with a bunch of zeros preceding and following that to fill out the data length. A "raw" CRC is one in which the CRC register is initialized with zeros and for which is there no final exclusive-or.